# How to change Icon if within 7 day else will change another icon by PHP

Tags: php

can ask how to change the icon if it is within 7 days else will change another icon?
and this is my code

```
<?php
     foreach($getEventList as $key => $value){
         $venue = $value['acd_schd_venue'];
         $title = $value['ach_name'];
         $date = $value['acd_schd_date'];
         $StartTime = $value['acd_start_time'];
         $EndTime = $value['acd_end_time'];
         $createdDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($value['acd_created_date']));
         $add7Day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['acd_created_date']. ' + 8 days'));

         if( $createdDate > $add7Day ) {
               echo '<span><img src="' . $image2 . '" /></span>';
         }else{
               echo '<span><img src="' . $image . '" /></span>';
         }
     }
```

Comment: The php date funtion will return a string. So your if statement will not work.

Comment: @Baracuda078   so can ask u how can i do or change to this code?

Comment: Learn to check the value of each variable and what exactly it outputs, before trying to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php date() funtion will return a string. So your if statement will not work.
strtotime() will return a unix timestamp wich can be used in a if statement to compare.

Comment: so your mean is $createdDate and $add7Day is wrong? if wrong, can teach me how to change this two code?

Comment: You allready have it in your code, just remove the date function and you have 2 timestamps you can compare in an if statement

Comment: how about this code?
$add7Day = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($value['acd_created_date']. ' + 8 days'));
because this code is for the date is $createdDate of ad 7 days?

Comment: and $createdDate value is a Datetime, not date